# int variable isn't changing after method execution

Tags: java, swing

Im currently working on a project so you might see some code that is not being used, anyways im trying to recieve a value of 1, 2 or 3 from the clas variable which i want returning from the method ClassSelect but everytime i run it i keep recieving that clas is still 0

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Deklaration
        int clas = 0;   //  | 1 = Warrior | 2 = Tank | 3 = Archer |
        ClassSelect(clas);
        System.out.println(clas);
    }

    private static int ClassSelect(int e) {
        while(e == 0){
        String classs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What class would you like to be? Warrior, Tank or Archer?");
        System.out.println(classs);

        if(classs.equals( "Warrior" ) || classs.equals( "warrior" )){
            e = e + 1;
        }
        else if(classs.equals( "Tank" ) || classs.equals( "tank" )){
            e = e + 2;
        }
        else if(classs.equals( "Archer" ) || classs.equals( "archer" )){
            e = e + 3;
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no class called " + classs);
            e = 0;
        }
        }
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassSelect(clas);` should be `clas = ClassSelect(clas);`

Comment: `extends JFrame`? Really, why?

Comment: BTW: `class.equalsIgnoreCase("Warrior")` is easier than `(classs.equals( "Warrior" ) || classs.equals( "warrior" ))`.

Comment: Warriors should be tanks, imo.

Answer (score 4):

Java is always pass-by-value.

Instead:

```
ClassSelect(clas);
```

It should be:

```
clas=ClassSelect(clas);
```